# Pytests doesn't collect tests from local directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've been looking all over the internet for an answer. They all tell me to make sure I do exactly what you can see I did below. I'm actually making this all during an online class in Pytest and it just doesn't work.

```
ls
TestCheckout.py  __init__.py    __pycache__   pytest.ini

cat TestCheckout.py 
def test_ConInstantiateCheckout():
    co = CheckOut()

pytest
=================================================== test session starts ====================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.2.0, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0
rootdir: /Users/ddow/dev/supermarket-kata
collected 0 items                                                                                                          

================================================== no tests ran in 0.01s
```

Does anyone know what gives? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pytest` follows a test discovery procedure. You can check the details [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery).

For your particular case, the file name should start with `test_` or end with `_test.py`. So renaming `TestCheckout.py` to `test_Checkout.py` would work. In case, you do not wish to change the name, you could provide the filename explicitly as in

```
user@qt01:~/folder$ pytest TestCheckout.py
============================================== test session starts ==============================================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-5.1.2, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0
sensitiveurl: .*
rootdir: /home/user/folder
plugins: needle-0.3.11, selenium-1.17.0, html-1.21.1, repeat-0.8.0, metadata-1.8.0, celery-4.3.0, base-url-1.4.1, variables-1.7.1
collected 1 item

TestCheckout.py .                                                                                         [100%]

=============================================== 1 passed in 0.03s ===============================================
user@qt01:~/folder$
```